# Select Case statement is turning Application.ScreenUpdating back on

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting Screen.Updating turned back on when running this sub.  Narrowed it down to this Select Case statement.  The code works it just keeps turning the updating back on.

```
If count > 1 Then
Select Case count
    Case 2
        Range("N10") = arrSkills(1)
    Case 3
        Range("N10") = arrSkills(1)
        Range("N11") = arrSkills(2)
    Case 4
        Range("N10") = arrSkills(1) & " " & arrSkills(2)
        Range("N11") = arrSkills(3)
    Case 5
        Range("N10") = arrSkills(1) & " " & arrSkills(2)
        Range("N11") = arrSkills(3) & " " & arrSkills(4)
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Make room for more Skills"
End Select

Else

End If
```

Here's the Worksheet_Change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Cells.count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Me.Range("Table[Name]"), Target) Is Nothing Then

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Code where the Select Case Statement is called

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There is nothing in that code that would cause `Application.ScreenUpdating` to be set back to `True`.  Are you sure you don't have a `Worksheet_Change` event that is being fired when N10 or N11 is modified, and **that** code is switching `ScreenUpdating` back on?

Comment: Also remember that single-stepping through your code will effectively treat `ScreenUpdating` as being `True`, so if that was how you narrowed it down to this piece of code it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: This sub does get called from a Worksheet_Change event.  But that is supposed to only trigger from a change in a different cell. (`If Target.Cells.count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Me.Range("Table[Name]"), Target) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: It's weird because if I `debug.print` from anywhere else in the code it returns `False`.  It's only when it's inside the Select Case statement that it's `True`

Comment: Please post the worksheet change event.  if the Application.ScreenUpdating is reset to true before exiting that sub any time a change is made on the worksheet it will turn it back on.

Comment: As I stated.  Since the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` is outside the `If...Then` it will fire every time a cell on that sheet is changed.  And since you change things with your code above, the screen updating is turned back on.  move the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` before the `End If`

Comment: Or set `Application.EnableEvents = False` prior to making changes to the cells, and switch it back to `True` after you finish making the changes - that will prevent the `Worksheet_Change` event being fired again half-way through your code.

Comment: Or just leave the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` out completely.  It Automatically turns back on after the code finishes.

Comment: I see!  I'm still new to all this but now it makes perfect sense.  Thank you that worked great.

Comment: Scott: Sometimes it inexplicably doesn't turn back on at the end of the routine in some of my projects. I always turn it on again just in case.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your changes to cells N10 and N11 are re-firing the `Worksheet_Change` event, and the last line of that event is setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.

It is usually best to disable events while processing an event (unless you really, **really** need to recursively call it for some reason).  Disabling events is achieved using

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

*Note: Be very careful that you always re-enable events when you finish, or else you will spend hours scratching your head wondering why your `Change` (etc) events are no longer being fired.*

So your code would be better written as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    If Intersect(Me.Range("Table[Name]"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'On Error statements are often more trouble than they are worth - but this is one
    '  occasion where it is dangerous not to use one.  You can't afford not to go
    '  through the statement re-enabling events.
    On Error GoTo ReEnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    '...
    If count > 1 Then
        Select Case count
            Case 2
                Range("N10") = arrSkills(1)
            Case 3
                Range("N10") = arrSkills(1)
                Range("N11") = arrSkills(2)
            Case 4
                Range("N10") = arrSkills(1) & " " & arrSkills(2)
                Range("N11") = arrSkills(3)
            Case 5
                Range("N10") = arrSkills(1) & " " & arrSkills(2)
                Range("N11") = arrSkills(3) & " " & arrSkills(4)
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Make room for more Skills"
        End Select
    Else
        '...
    End If
    '...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ReEnableEvents:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```